# Select more columns with GROUP_CONCAT( ) according to lowest date

Tags: mysql

I have one table accounts. I have written following query

```
chk_account= mysql_query("SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT user_id ) AS userlist
                                FROM  `accounts` 
                                ");
```

From this I get users id only. With this query I also want to fetch data price and date with column name price and created but I need only to select with lowest date

I have table structure like this:

```
id      user_id         price       created
1       31              10          2013-04-09 17:30:15
2       32              20          2013-04-10 20:24:40
3       31              30          2013-04-11 04:44:25
4       33              40          2013-04-12 05:47:18
5       34              50          2013-04-13 19:54:15
6       34              50          2013-04-14 14:27:15
7       35              10          2013-04-15 13:54:45
8       35              60          2013-04-16 12:24:35
9       35              10          2013-04-17 20:34:10
```

Comment: what is the basis for your lowest date? or can you shou us your desired output?

Comment: I am getting only users id from above query, and if I add price and created date also in it, when I dump the price it shows me 9 prices. I only want user id price with lowest date created

Comment: how will you output look like? do you want them on to be grouped by it? or the result can be on one record only? how? it is not clear.

Comment: I want to use prices and need to multiply by a number. So once I get price with user id, so I use user id in fetching data from user table and price to display price according to users

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you want the earliest date and price for each user.  You can do this using `group_concat()`, using a query such as:

```
select USER_ID,
       substring_index(group_concat(price order by created), ',', 1) as price,
       min(created)
from accounts a
group by user_id
```